# Conditional Rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have many meshes to render, some quite big. So I want to use Conditional Rendering.

here is an excerpt of the code

```
glColorMaski(0, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);    //  not written in the framebuffer
glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, QueryName); // Beginning of the samples count query
    // render simple bounding box
glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);

// render only if a sample pass the occlusion query.
glColorMaski(0, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);    // written in the framebuffer
glBindBufferRange(..);
glBeginConditionalRender(QueryName, GL_QUERY_WAIT);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, &glm::vec4(1.0f)[0]); // ****** all other meshes will be erased *******
    // render complex and heavy mesh
glEndConditionalRender();
```

It works but the problem is that Clearing the frame buffer before the second rendering will erase any previous meshes.

So how can I use a different depth buffer or any buffer binding to use Occlusion Query on ALL the meshes?

I am using OpenGL core 4.5

Comment: Wouldn't all the occlusion queries force many synchronization points? AFAIK some games do a "depth pre-pass" where they render all meshes to the depth buffer only, and then render meshes in the same order with `glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL)`.

Comment: Sounds great, but how to identify the meshes that passed the deph test from the ones that failed?

Comment: You leave that up to the depth test, I think, so just render everything and let the depth test pick out which fragments to show.

Answer (score 3):

Following Botje's advice, I use a "depth pre-pass" to determine which meshes are to be fully rendered.
Each mesh has a boolean (bOcclusion) to keep track of the depth test result 
It works just fine.
some peudo-code

```
// Main rendering loop
// setup matrix and options...........
 // ** not writing in the framebuffer
glColorMaski(0, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE); 

foreach(mesh,vectorMesh){ // first pass
     mesh->render(glm::dmat4,uint optionOcclusion);
      }

glClearDepth(1.0f);
// ** writing in the framebuffer
glColorMaski(0, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE); 

foreach(mesh,vectorMesh){ // second pass
     mesh->render(glm::dmat4,uint optionRender);
      } 

// **************  mesh rendering  *************
// mesh has a boolean (bOcclusion) showing depth test result 

void mesh::render(glm::dmat4,uint options)
{
 if(options & RENDER_MODE_OCCLUSION){
  glClearDepth(1.0f);
  glBeginQuery(GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, queryOcclusion);
   // ....setup VAO  and buffers for bounding box
   // render bounding box
  glEndQuery(GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED);
  glFinish();  // make sure GL_QUERY_RESULT is available
  uint nb;
  glGetQueryObjectuiv(queryOcclusion,GL_QUERY_RESULT,&nb);
  bOcclusion = (nb>0);
  return;
  }
 else if(!bOcclusion)
  return;

 // normal complete rendering
 // ....setup VAO  and buffers for full mesh
 // render full mesh
}
```

Comment: Why do you render the depth-only part with a cleared depth buffer? That will mean that you do a full render for meshes that may be totally obscured..

Comment: I also wonder if you can get any more savings by setting the glDepthFunc to GL_EQUAL, as I remarked in a comment. That would allow you to skip rasterization for parts of partially-obscured meshes

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly where I should use the glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL).  In the main loop or on each mesh rendering?  And use it in rendering bounding box or full rendering? And do we still need glBeginConditionalRender ?

I could also render the mesh ID in a texture and then pick the visible meshes with glReadPixels.

Comment: After rendering every mesh to the depth buffer, you know exactly what the final depth will be for every pixel on the screen. If you now draw your meshes *without* clearing the depth buffer, the gpu can immediately discard any triangles whose depth exceeds the final depth. This will completely remove overdraw and thus save time by avoiding rasterizing fragments that will be covered by a later mesh anyway. EDIT: I just realized that you do not need a different depth function at all, so nevermind.